# Python 3.6 tk ScrolledText on TopLevel won't insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am having issues with the code below when I use Pyinstaller to compile an executable.

I am attempting to open a second GUI window using TopLevel, adding a ScrolledText widget to it, then take the output of `ipconfig /all` and put it in the ScrolledText.

I stripped the code down to just the code relevant to this issue. If I run the python file directly, or compile with Pyinstaller without the --windowed command `pyinstaller --onefile toolbox.py`, then everything appears to work.

When I compile with --windowed `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed toolbox.py`, then the TopLevel window opens and I get the error message listed in the code and the ScrolledText widget is blank.

I have confirmed that using a normal string on the `txt.insert` command does work, so the issues appear to be with the `os.popen` command. I did attempt to use `subprocess.check_output` in place of `os.popen` but I get the same error message. Also, assigning the `os.popen` command to a variable then inserting the variable in `txt.insert` has the same result.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import os
import sys


def netIPInfo():
    """Open a second window, displays output of ipconfig /all."""
    window2 = Toplevel()
    window2.title("NIC IP Info")
    window2.geometry("663x650")
    txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window2, width=80, height=40)
    txt.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    try:
        txt.insert(INSERT, os.popen("ipconfig /all").read())  # ISSUE!!
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", e)  # Error message below
        # {<class 'OSError'}
        # {[WinError 6] The handle is invalid}
        # {<traceback object at 0x02EEB260>}

    txt.configure(state="disabled")

    window2.mainloop()

# Primary GUI Window
window = Tk()
window.title("ProTech QST")
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Network')
lfr5 = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, text="Information")
lfr5.pack(fill=X)
btn30 = Button(lfr5, text="NIC IP Info")
btn30.config(width=18, command=netIPInfo)
btn30.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**

I was playing with the code some more and found that if I run pyinstaller with --windowed but without --onefile it works. Same for running pyinstaller with --onefile but without --windowed. So is this an issue not with the code, but with pyinstaller?

Comment: Try using subprocess with the shell argument instead: `txt.insert(INSERT, subprocess.check_output("ipconfig /all", shell=True))`

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference.  I hadn't noticed this before, but the ScrolledText widget should be disabled/non-editable after the insert and it is editable.  So txt.insert and txt.configure are being ignored?

Comment: Updated thread above, txt.configure is working once I used `try/except` on the insert line.  Doing insert with just a string does work, so it's only when I try to call a command using `popen` or `check_output`.

Comment: Re-wrote issue request to meet Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable.  Code has been stripped to minimal, and explanation re-written.

Comment: Have you tried separating the line `txt.insert(INSERT, os.popen("ipconfig /all").read())  # ISSUE!!` into three lines as: `process = os.popen("ipconfig /all"); txt.insert(INSERT, process.read()); process.close()`?

Comment: @Nae I tried this method and I get the same Handle is Invalid error.